# c# binary writer delete some portion of text in a file

Tags: c#, .net

I am writing the below structure in to the file using Binary Writer.
File Structure:
Num of Employees {employee num & name, employee1 num & name, employee2 num & name...}.

I will get a command with employee num to delete that particualr employee details and update Num of employees feild accordingly.

What is the best way to do the above operation?

Regards
Raju

Comment: you should store your data in a database, it would make things much easier...

Comment: You should do as Thomas said and look into using a Database.  If you want something application based you can checkout SQLite.  There is a .NET provider for this and it's very easy to use.  You could also look into the SQL Server Compact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is a little unclear, but when I'm working with a File I always try to deserialize structued data like that to classes.

In general, you'd get a list of Employee objects from the file, remove the item you want, and then write the list back out to the file (or DB, or any other thing you need to write the data to).  Quick example (I haven't tried this, so it might not compile as is:)

```
    //EmpList is a List<Employee>
    public void DeleteEmployee(int employeeNumber)
    {
    //Assumes you will never have multiple entries with the same EE#, or that
    //if you do you want to delete all records
```

for(int i = EmpList.Count -1; i>= 0; i--)
   {
       if(EmpList[i].EmployeeNumber == employeeNumber)
       EmpList.Remove(EmpList[i]);
   }

   //Call code to reserialize (to file, db, whatever)
}